How to Safely Handle C# Class Instances in C++?
I am trying to call a C++ function from C# and pass a C# class instance as an argument. My goal is to safely handle the class instance in C++ without causing errors or unexpected behavior. And I want to load members in C++. (READ ONLY)
When passing a structure as an argument, I use GCHandle.Alloc to lock the object. However, when I try to lock a reference type (like a class instance), GCHandle.Alloc gives me an error.
What is the recommended way to safely pass and handle a C# class instance in C++? I've reviewed similar questions, but I couldn't find a solution that directly addresses this specific scenario. Any guidance, examples, or best practices would be greatly appreciated. I am looking for a method that does not use C++/CLI if possible.
For example:
C#
public class DummyClass
{
  [DllImport( "examlple.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall )]
  public static extern void CppExecute( AppParameter _parameter );

  [StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode )]
  public class AppParameter
  {
    public Guid Id { get; init; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public Int32 Value { get; init; } = 0;
    public String Name { get; init; } = "ABC";
  }

  public Parameter{ get; set; } = new AppParameter();

  public void Execute()
  {
      // 1. Allocate unmanaged memory, copy the data there, and pass it to C++. It can be accessed in C++, but it needs to be copied.
      IntPtr pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal( Marshal.SizeOf( AppParameter ) );
      Marshal.StructureToPtr( Parameter, pointer, false );
      CppExecute( pointer );
      Marshal.FreeHGlobal( pointer );

      // 2. It seems that it cannot be accessed from C++.
      GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc( Parameter, GCHandleType.Normal );
      IntPtr ptr = GCHandle.ToIntPtr( handle );
      CppExecute( ptr );
      handle.Free();

      // 3. Can I access it from C++ as well, and is it safe to use?
      CppExecute( (AppParameter)Parameter );

      // 4. Error
      GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc( Parameter, GCHandleType.Pinned );
      CppExecute( (AppParameter)Parameter );
      handle.Free();
  }
}

C++
class AppParameter
{
  GUID Id;
  int Value;
  const wchar_t* Name;
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall CppExecute( AppParameter* _parameter )
{
  AppParameter* test =  _parameter;
}


Avoid dllimport, use C++/cli  (managed C++ extensions) and writing explicit adapter code. There is some stuff you need to do to prevent garbage collector from moving around memory that C++ is using.

The public AppParameter line is missing the property name, if this isn't the error you are talking about, please add the error to your question.

I forgot to mention it earlier, but I am looking for a solution that does not use C++/CLI.
Additionally, I added the error message to the code:
System.ArgumentException: 'Object contains references. Arg_ParamName_Name'.

A solution that's based on managed code, only is off the table? From my experience, such "bridges" tend to be rather brittle, especially if you don't have a c++-genius, who is also well versed in c#/.Net, at your disposal 24/7.

I want to run a specific part in C++, but I need to pass a C# class member as read-only. Would it still be difficult unless I am a genius?

It's better to have POD interop between C++ or C# which makes debugger much simpler. Unless you have an expert for both C++ and C#. Unless you really need zero copy. Oh.. it seems like you referred to struct... Then it should be okay.

The third method in the code in question (the simplest one) allowed me to get the class members on the C++ side. Would it be safe to use this method as read-only? (Will it be garbage collected?)

Method 1 copies the string implicitly using Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni and is leaking memory due to the lack of Marshal.DestroyStructure and Method 3 implicitly does method 1 under the hood, and is only safe during the call

You cannot safely access any class members from C++, since you do not know the memory layout of the class. An object needs to be pinned to get a pointer to it, and that will both mess up compactation, and increase the risk for memory leaks.

Unlike structs, You cannot use C# reference type objects from pure C++ . But you can get an opaque handle to it with
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc( AppParameter, GCHandleType.Normal );

With this handle you can use GCHandle.ToIntPtr on it to get the equivalent of a void* in C++, you cannot access this pointer content from C++
You can also store this IntPtr in other structs so those structs can be pinned and passed to c++, (the struct should contain a void* in c++, or an opaque pointer)
To call methods on this object you need to call a C# static function from C++ (see How to call a delegate in C# (Windows forms) from an unmanaged C++ dll) and this function will convert this IntPtr back to GCHandle with GCHandle.FromIntPtr then use its Target property to get back the original C# object. the object can be moved in memory, but this doesn't matter as it won't be accessed from C++. The C++ code only holds the GCHandle.

If you want to call C# methods directly from C++ then you should use C++/CLI or COM but they are windows only, while the mentioned method works on any platform.
There is also Qtdotnet which generates the static callbacks at runtime so you don't have to write them yourself, but it follows Qt licensing (check website, mostly GPL or LGPL or commercial)
There are also wrapper generators like SWIG to generate wrapper functions for you, but i haven't tried it before, and AFAIK it wraps C++ in C# while you want to wrap C# in C++
The dotnet (dotnet 8) native API is not as good as others like Java and python, and i hope it improves in the future.

For just String you can use Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi (and its unicode alternative) to get an IntPtr that is equivalent to a char* in C++ and you can access it but you need to free it later. Note the unicode one is char16_t not wchar_t except on platforms where they are equal (windows). Also C# automatically calls it when marshalling structs that contain strings, which is why Method 3 in the question works.

Thank you for your answer. >I cannot access the contents of this pointer from C++. Why is it impossible?
For example, I could access: GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(AppParameter, GCHandleType.Normal); IntPtr ptr = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle); However, this method not want to use because it involves copying. I don't need to call the class method, I just want to access the class members directly from C++. It can be read-only.
I still don't fully understand the information you gave me, but I will do my best to read up on it. Thank you very much.

@kinton c# objects don't have a specific layout, they have a header which you cannot access, and the layout of members after it is unspecified, it is nothing that c++ can portably understand, though some runtimes like mono provided a stable string layout which could be accessed from c++, this is not true for dotnet core

@kinton for strings it will involve copying to create the native buffer (also conversion from char16 to char) but for opaque types it is just a pointer, no copies are made.
